# Firebase Storage "error sending network request GET"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have this problem with Firebase Storage where Glide can't load images to ImageViews.

Looking at the logcat, I get a continuous stream of:

```
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request GET
```

these are my firebase dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.7.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0"
```

this is the code for glide:

```
StorageReference generage_ref(String uid, String image_name){
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storage_ref = storage.getReference();
        return storage_ref.child(uid+"/"+image_name+".jpg");
    }

void load_round(Context context, StorageReference storageReference, ImageView imageView){
        GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(storageReference)
            .circleCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    }
```

which I would call as:

```
load_round(context,
           generate_ref("some_uid", "some_image_name"),
           imageview)
```

I tried running my working backup code from ten days ago but I get the same error which was not present back then..

Funny thing is, when I opened my VPN, All the images load just fine.
I hope someone can help cause I am truly lost now.

Answer (score 2):

This is for those who will encounter the same problem in the future..

I have encountered this problem before and had a conversation through email with google support. You can fix this problem by changing your network provider or by using VPN. This has nothing to do with your code and the error will be gone in like a week or so.

Comment: Correct. The the problem just disappeared on its own after some time.

Comment: My huawei phone still receiving the error. Currently, the app only work in emulator and other phones.

Comment: the problem lies in dns server, I tried to set a private dns e.g. one.one.one.one from cloudflare. Google dns not working.